# Execution of scripts was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableScript property to enable it

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, xslt, custom-field-types, xml

I have created a custom field in SharePoint 2010. I have a xsl file which does the Xslt rendering for item display in list view. I need to add some C# code to the xslt code. So I included code as below:

1)

```
xml:user="urn::my-scripts" in the xsl:stylesheet tag.
```

2)

```
<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
    <msxsl:assembly name="System.Web"/>
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Web"/><![CDATA[public string GetDate(string DateFormat){return DateTime.Now.ToString(DateFormat);}]]>
  </msxsl:script>
```

3) And used it in the code as

```
<xsl:value-of select="user:GetDate('dddd, dd MMMM yyyy')"/>
```

But, I get an error saying:

> "Execution of scripts was prohibited. Use the
>   XsltSettings.EnableScript property to enable it. An error occurred at
>   C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\template\layouts\xsl"

Since its a custom field, I have only the XML file to declare the custom field and the XSLT to render it, when it comes to displaying in a list item view.

Though in some scenario's the XmlTransform class is used to set the XsltSettings.EnableScript property through a C# code file, here it doesn't seem to be feasible.

Is there a way to set the EnableScript property in the XSLT or XML ? Or any other ways ?